# Создание новый Excel файлов на основе одного файла

Tags: python, pandas, excel

У меня есть файл Excel, в котором есть поле "номер" в нем номерные значения. Мне нужно создать новые Excel файлы на основе этого столбца, чтоб строка у которой "номер" равен 1 в один файл Excel, если равен 2 то в другой и т.д. Пробовал через groupBy,но знаю что не работает.Так же название всегда разные дата в таком формате и "шаблон"

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.read_excel("./09.21 hpl шаблон.xls")

category=df.groupby('номер')

xlsx_path =os.path.dirname(file)+ r"result.xlsx"


for period, data in df.groupby('номер'):
    
    data.to_excel(xlsx_path, sheet_name = period)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Пробовал через groupBy,но знаю что не работает". Откуда знаете? Пока даже не видно запись в разные файлы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691133/split-pandas-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-using-groupby

Comment: Там в for, через data.to_excel. нашел на просто что так делали, но так не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По существу подход правильный - если немного "допилить" ваш код, то все прекрасно работает. Нужно только формировать новое имя файла на каждой итерации цикла, чтобы очередной файл не затирал предыдущий.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

file = r'c:\test\primer шаблон.xlsx'
xlsx_path = os.path.dirname(file)
cur_date = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime("%m.%d") # формирование текущей даты в нужном формате
for period, data in pd.read_excel(file).groupby('Номер'):
    data.to_excel(xlsx_path + rf'\{cur_date} шаблон {period}.xlsx', sheet_name=str(period), index=False)
```

Формируются файлы:

```
09.20 шаблон 5.xlsx
09.20 шаблон 4.xlsx
09.20 шаблон 3.xlsx
09.20 шаблон 2.xlsx
09.20 шаблон 1.xlsx
```

Comment: Этот файл будет находиться в папке с excel файлом,и каждый день этот скрипт должен разбивать разные Excel файл. То есть сегодня файл называется 09.21 шаблон, завтра 09.22 шаблон и т.д, либо вообще 10.21 шаблон, в зависимости от того от какого числа хотят отформатировать шаблон

Comment: Дополнил решение

Comment: Я неправильно объяснил, каждый раз будет меняться исходный файл который фильтруется. Сегодня может file = r'c:\test\primer1 шаблон.xlsx', а завтра file = r'c:\test\primer шаблон.xlsx'

Comment: А как программе узнать, какой сегодня файл обрабатывать?

Comment: Возможно ли чтоб программа искала в папке Excel файл по условию что в названии должна  определенная подстрочка нему применяла

Comment: Возможно, но это уже совершенно другой вопрос

Comment: Спасибо тогда буду искать ответ на этот вопрос